# How do I make a parameter default to the value of another parameter in Scala?

Tags: scala

Why can't I do the following:

`def multiply(a: Int, b: Int = a) = a * b`

or

`case class Point(x: Int, y: Int = x)`

Is there another way to achieve the same? The reason I need this is because sometimes, the arguments having different values is more the exception than the rule. Take for example:

`case class User(name: String, age: String, description: String, displayName: String = name, online: Boolean = false)`

In 90% of the cases, display name and name should be the same, but in a few edge cases, it should not. Having one parameter default to the value of another would be very useuful. Is there a way to do this? And if not, why?

Comment: did you try `(a: Int)(b: Int = a)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Parameters in a parameter list can refer to argument values in previous parameter lists, similar to how type inference can refer to types in previous parameter lists:

```
def multiply(a: Int)(b: Int = a) = a * b

case class Point(x: Int)(y: Int = x)

case class User(name: String, age: String, description: String)(displayName: String = name, online: Boolean = false)
```

should work.

Comment: Does not seem to work. I get an error while creating an object as Point(3)

Comment: The factory method is defined with two parameter lists, so you have to supply two argument lists: `Point(3)()`

Comment: Then I get error: value y is not a member of Point while res0.y. What am I missing? I can only call x as res0.x where res0 is an instance on Point.

Comment: Only constructor parameters from the first parameter list of a case class constructor are implicitly converted into `val`s. If you want parameters from the other parameter lists available as `val`s, you have to annotate them as always. (Note that AFAIK, the automatic hashcode and equals generation as well automatic `copy` method also only cover the first parameter list, but you will have to confirm that with the language spec.)

Answer (score 1):

One way can be to define case class as

```
case class User(name: String, age: String, description: String, displayName: String, online: Boolean = false) {
    def this(name: String, age: String, description: String, online: Boolean = true) =
    this(name, age, description, name, online)
}
```

Then you can create case class as

```
  val user = new User("User name", "5", "description")
  //> user  : User = User(User name,5,description,User name,true)
  user.displayName
  //> res0: String = User name
  val userWithDisplayName = new User("User name", "5", "description", "displayName")
  //> userWithDisplayName  : User = User(User name,5,description,displayName,false)
```

You can also override apply method in the companion object. That way you will not have to write new before creating the object

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)
case class User(name: String, age: String, description: String, displayName: String, online: Boolean = false)
object User {
  def apply(name: String, age: String, description: String, online: Boolean) =
    new User(name, age, description, name, online)
}
// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.
defined class User
defined module User
scala> User("User name", "5", "description", "displayName")
res0: User = User(User name,5,description,displayName,false)
scala> User("User name", "5", "description", true)
res1: User = User(User name,5,description,User name,true)
```